# by no means / by no manner of

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

What is the difference between these words? Can it be interchangeable?

> He was ***by no means*** a cruel man.
>
> He was ***by no manner of means*** a cruel man.

Comment: Have you looked in any dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two phrases have, I believe, the same meaning, and are technically interchangeable, however:

> He was by no means a cruel man.

Is definitely much more common and natural.  The second sentence:

> He was by no manner of means a cruel man.

sounds distinctly outdated and embellished, the sort of thing I would expect to find in a Jane Austen novel from the 1800s.  It would definitely sound strange in anything written in modern times, so I would not recommend using it in your own writing/speaking.

Comment: What if it were the following: *He was by no **possible** means a cruel man.* Or this: *He was by no **conceivable** means a cruel man.* Neither of those sentences are outdated. Does it change your analysis in terms of added meaning? I'm more curious about the addition of the adjective than the specific word used.

Comment: Those two examples do indeed seem a bit less dated, although I think "by no means" has become such a set phrase in most modern speech that the act of adding any additional adjectives to it does still sound a bit unusual, and possibly overly dramatic.

Comment: What I was really getting at was the difference in meaning. To me, the adjectives add emphasis that the plain versions lack, and which could offset any concerns about a possibly dated phrasing. I would argue that the adjectives could serve a reasonable purpose in the right context. (As a simple sentence, however, it's difficult to see it.)